# org.apache.spark.SparkException:Job aborted due to stage failure :java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm facing an issue running spark jon on hadoop/yarn cluster it run's fine in local mode but fails in cluster mode due to this null pointer exception 
i'm using spark 1.6.2 and scala 2.10.6 both in local and cluster , the application is a streaming application streaming data from kakfa, here is the code where i'm getting the null pointer, i'm able to get data for some of the batches but for some i get the null pointer's as the null pointer's pile up the job fails here is the code snippet of where it fails 
DevMain.scala

```
 Line 1 val lines: DStream[String,Array[Byte]] = myConsumer.createDefaultStream()

 Line 2 val keyDeLines = lines.map(lme.aParser);
```

---

this is createDefaultStream()

```
def createDefaultStream(): DStream[(String,Array[Byte])] = {

    val consumerConfProps = List("zookeeper.connect","group.id","zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms")
    val kafkaConf = Utils.getSubProps(props,consumerConfProps)
    val topicArray = props.getProperty("topics").split(",")
    val topicMap = {
      topicArray.map((_, props.getProperty("numthreads").toInt)).toMap
    }

    KafkaUtils.createStream[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder](ssc,
      kafkaConf,
      topicMap,
      StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER
    )
```

---

this is lme.parser

```
def aParser(x: (String,Array[Byte])): Option[Map[String,Any]] = {

    logInfo("Entered lme: ")


    val decodeTry = Injection.invert(x._2)
    decodeTry match {
      case Failure(e) => {
        logInfo(s"Could not decode binary data: " + e.getStackTrace)
        None
      }
      case Success(eventPojo) => {

        val bs: String = eventPojo.toString

        logInfo("json: " + bs)
      }
}
```

code never enter's the 'lme.aParser' function in the null pointer cases i have put logging on line1 of lme.parser

here is the stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at DevMain$$anonfun$5.apply(DevMain.scala:2)

at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1631)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm new to running spark on cluster could some one please point me in the right direction

Note: i know within the map it's trying to iterate over elements of dstream lines ..but when empty it's failing , but from the reading i have done on dsteam empty batches should not cause a failure please correct me if i'm wrong ....Have done my share of digging around on this some folks pointed it as failing to convert from java iterator to scala iterator within spark code, other's have pointed to this might be a bug in serialization code of spark ..not sure which way to head to

Comment: Can you please post your Spark_submit script

Comment: spark-submit --verbose --class DevMain --master yarn-cluster --deploy-mode cluster --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" --files "hdfs://hdfs-name-node:8020/user/hadoopuser/log4j.properties" hdfs://hdfs-name-node:8020/user/hadoopuser/streaming_2.10-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar hdfs://hdfs-name-node:8020/user/hadoopuser/enriched.properties

Comment: lme.parser is your user defined Map. might be this is not able to handle the Null values .

Comment: like i mentioned it's not entering lme.parser ....i have put logging in line1 of lme.parser

Comment: Could you add the code of the parser? `lme.aParser`?

Comment: i tried the StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2 the application itself is not starting

Answer (score 0):

I my opinion,it because data loss.The producer send message and the consumer receive message,but when the network is traffic or the data in memory not flush,the data may be loss.you can set this replication factor on a topic-by-topic basis,the other reason also lead data loss.

Comment: Could you please provide more details ....please point me to exactly what to do...

Comment: i'm consuming only one topic

Comment: also i tried to apply this filter but it didn't help val keyDeLines = filteredLines.filter(x => x != null).map(lme.aParser)

Comment: val keyDeLines = lines.filter(x => x != null).map(lme.aParser) didn't work either

Comment: Can you post your detail code ? From your describe ,i can't point the error.

Comment: def createDefaultStream(): DStream[String,Array[Byte] = {

    val consumerConfProps = List("zookeeper.connect","group.id","zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms")
    val kafkaConf = Utils.getSubProps(props,consumerConfProps)
    val topicArray = props.getProperty("topics").split(",")
    val topicMap = {
      topicArray.map((_, props.getProperty("numthreads").toInt)).toMap
    }

    KafkaUtils.createStream[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder](ssc,
      kafkaConf,
      topicMap,
      StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER
    )

Comment: try to chang StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER  to StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2